# G++ and STD 11 has problems with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, constexpr

Im trying use the same constexpr in g++ and clang++, both latest version and with param "-std=c++11". Clang compiles without problem, but G++ return error. 
The source is:

```
#include <functional>

enum class LoggerLevel : unsigned {
    NO_LEVEL = 0,
    VERBOSE = 1 << 0,
    DEBUG = 1 << 1,
    INFO = 1 << 2,
    WARNING = 1 << 3,
    ERROR = 1 << 4,
    FATAL = 1 << 5,
    ALL_LEVELS = 0 | VERBOSE | DEBUG | INFO | WARNING | ERROR | FATAL,
};

constexpr LoggerLevel operator|(LoggerLevel lhs, LoggerLevel rhs) noexcept {
    return static_cast<LoggerLevel>(static_cast<unsigned>(lhs) | static_cast<unsigned>(rhs));
}

constexpr LoggerLevel& operator|=(LoggerLevel& lhs, LoggerLevel rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs = lhs | rhs;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = LoggerLevel::ALL_LEVELS;
    return 0;
}
```

And the error is:

```
<source>: In function 'constexpr LoggerLevel& operator|=(LoggerLevel&, LoggerLevel)':

<source>:19:16: error: expression '(lhs = operator|(lhs, rhs))' is not a constant expression

     return lhs = lhs | rhs;

            ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

And the godbolt example:

https://godbolt.org/z/M6ERms

Thanks with any help.

Comment: Try c++14. In C++11 constexpr functions are very limited. Somebody can do analysis based on the wording of Standard.

Comment: I believe it's as simple as assignments not being supported in `constexpr` functions in C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile for at least the C++14 standard as prior to C++14, the core [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) evaluation would **not** evaluate an assignment or a compound assignment operator which is what you have in:

```
return lhs = lhs | rhs;
```

The relevant chapter in the C++11 draft is **5.19.2 Constant expressions** (emphasis mine):

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   ...
>
> - an **assignment** or a compound assignment

Comment: I have accepted it, but in my case the code is generate by Dropbox Djinni tool, that say the code is compatible with C++11 :(